# Connect to mysql database in Android with java

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have installed mysql in my computer.and also have jetty..
My requirement:-
I have a **database student with table name ari**;
ari table is:-

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 22 | Sandy |
+----+-------+
```

from My Android program I want to fetch it from database..I have done this:-
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String pass = "root";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testDB();
    }
public void testDB() {
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            String result = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ari");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
while(rs.next()) {
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                        }
            tv.setText(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tv.setText(e.toString());
        }   
    }
}
```

and **activity_main.xml** is:--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the manifext file is:---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.TourBus.info"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But the problem is when I run that program in my android phone or emulator it is showing that:--

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:  
Could not create connection to database server.
```

I also have the jar file:--

```
mysql-connector-java
```

can anybody help me??pls

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: can you do that et al? To the best of my knowledge you need a webservice to connect to your database as your database is running on some server and your application is running on mobile

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar,about site example is very good..but it is php..I don't know php..Is there any example in java+android+mysql??

Comment: @subhodeepchatterjee first u think your device that connect on use panel so u think what u want to do

Comment: in android there is also buit in database sqlite database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486119/how-can-android-apps-access-mysql

Comment: @ Naveen Tamrakar yes dear..I know about sqlite..But I want to store it to the mysql with java..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same host, use the alias `10.0.2.2` to refer to the host computer's loopback interface. From the emulator's perspective, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` refers to its own loopback interface. So change

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
```

to

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2/student";
```

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

#### EDIT

In your  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` try commenting out `skip-networking` by adding `#` at the beginning of that line.

If that doesn't solve your problem try checking this [Solving a “communications link failure” with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772407/4083590) for solving your `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationException:communication link failure` error after changing your `url` as shown above.

Comment: I have tried this one....
but its saying,"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationException:communication link failure

;...The last package sent successfully to the server ..The driver has not receive any packets from server"

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';` use this command and check your port no. is `3306` or not. Also try the url without port no

Comment: where??in terminal????
iirc-Dell-DXP061:~$ SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
SHOW: command not found

Comment: "C:\Program Files\mysql\bin\my.ini try commenting out skip-networking by adding # at the beginning of that line."

what will be the command for ubuntu?