# Can I use firebase database for both desktop and mobile application

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, firebase

I have developed a Library Management System in java using mysql database.
Now I want to also built a android application for library users to see which book they have issued.

whole idea is that first desktop application collects data then as it gets internet connection it syncs that data to host server after that library users can see that relative data on their phones using android application (That I am going to built).

According to my knowledge I can't use mysql database in android application.  Can I ?

Second thing I was thinking to use firebase database. Using firebase database my desktop application will sync data into host server and then clients can check their relavent data.

Can I do this with firebase database.
Or if that's possible with mysql database then that more better for me.

Any suggestions .PLz
Second thing is that

Comment: Yes, you can use mysql with java in Android. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074226/connect-to-mysql-database-in-android-with-java

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do it with Firebase databases, that is Realtime or Cloud Firestore.
In this case Realtime will be more suitable because you want the data to change for both the android and desktop clients to change in realtime, but you must decide according to your needs.

Secondly, in your SQL database, you might have data specific to each user, i.e. maybe subscription or maybe which books they have . You can easily put that in the Cloud Firestore. However an important thing to note it is a NoSQL database so it works with collections and documents rather than columns and tables in sql. You should read about NoSQL databases first

And thus you will be good to go